# Upgrade dedicated video memory in i9 Intel uhd graphics 630

Tags: windows-11, intel-graphics

I've got a new PC i9 10980HK with integrated graphic Intel UHD Graphics 630 iGPU, however, my experience is been not too good with video performance, for instance, when I move Google Chrome then the CPU 0 goes over 80%; I was wondering how I can increase the video memory.
I tried a couple of steps to increase the memory on Registry Editor in Windows 11, but it is still slow and has been showing 128MB.

BIOS
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEwlN.jpg)

TASK MANAGER
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0EMJ.png)

DRIVERS
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv8u0.png)

REGEDIT
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jyz0C.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Intel iGPUs do not have dedicated RAM, the best they have is RAM permanently stolen from your CPU RAM. If you want dedicated graphics RAM then you will have to buy a dedicated graphics card, that is not likely possible with a laptop.

Comment: integrated GPUs just aren't great in general. note that while you spent on an i9, the UDH Graphics 630 is the same as you'd find in an 10th gen i3. if you  have the option, install a discrete video card. https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/201894/intel-core-i310105-processor-6m-cache-up-to-4-40-ghz.html

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the screenshots from the Intel Display driver control panel and indicate what version of Intels display driver you actually have installed. While I agree performance will not be what you were expecting.  The iGPU can use more and probably should have more than 8 MB accessible to it